# Splitting text with BeautifulSoup findall()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a text from the forum website, it works good but there's a problem with split the text

```
s = "Username[^\"]+<br"
r = requests.get("https://example.com/threads/73956/page2", headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
comments = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'wwCommentBody'})
for div in comments:
    bq = div.find('blockquote',{'class':'postcontent restore'})
    result = re.findall(s, r.text)
    print (result)
```

It prints like this:

`['Username: Marvel<br']`

How can I make it extracts to the last letter of the username value `Marvel` without the `<br`and `['']`?

```
<div class="wwCommentBody">
     <blockquote class="postcontent restore " style="padding: 10px;">Username: 
     leetibrahim<br>
    Number: 2       
     </blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the captured `<br`, change your regex to the following:

```py
s = '(Username[^"]+)(?:<br)'
```

Or, with the manual escape:

```py
s = "(Username[^\"]+)(?:<br)"
```

as those are equivalent. [More about non-capturing groups.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions)

It's printing as `['Username: leetibrahim']` because it is a list. To get the first element of the list:

```py
print(result[0])
```

To get all elements of the list:

```py
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

To get just the last `'m'` from the username:

```py
result[0][-1]
```

That works by getting the first element (index 0) of the list and then the last element (index -1) of the string.

Comment: You saved me!! thank you so much, please I've a last little question, if I want to get another string with its value which it will be like this
`Username: leetibrahim Number: 2`
How can i do it

Comment: If I understand you correctly: `print(result[0])`

Comment: didn't work actually, it prints only `Username: leetibrahim` there's something should I edit it in my regax?

Comment: You can edit your regex, like this: `s = "(Username[^\"]+)(?:</blockquote>)"` and then remove the `<br>` like this: `print(result[0].replace("<br>", ""))`.

Comment: you can also do it with bs4: `print(bq.get_text())`

Comment: Bro I don't know what to tell you but thank you!! ❤

Comment: No problem! Just upvote my comments/answer if they were helpful 